# How to get information like capital, currency, language, population about a country in simple way using SPARQL from DBPEDIA

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

How to get information like capital, currency, language, population about a country in simple way using SPARQL from DBPEDIA.
Is there a simple way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for this problem,
I figured out a query that returns all the required fields,

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ?country ?population ?capital ?currency WHERE {
   {?country rdf:type 
 <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/WikicatMemberStatesOfTheUnitedNations> .
  ?country  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/populationTotal> ?population .
  ?country  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/capital> ?capital .
  ?country  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/currency> ?currency .}
UNION
  {?country rdf:type <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Country> .
  ?country  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/populationTotal> ?population .
  ?country  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/capital> ?capital .
  ?country  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/currency> ?currency .}
}
```

[SPARQL Result](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fcountry%20%3Fpopulation%20%3Fcapital%20%3Fcurrency%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%7B%3Fcountry%20rdf%3Atype%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fclass%2Fyago%2FWikicatMemberStatesOfTheUnitedNations%3E%20.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fcountry%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FpopulationTotal%3E%20%3Fpopulation%20.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fcountry%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2Fcapital%3E%20%3Fcapital%20.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fcountry%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2Fcurrency%3E%20%3Fcurrency%20.%7D%0D%0AUNION%0D%0A%20%20%7B%3Fcountry%20rdf%3Atype%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FCountry%3E%20.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fcountry%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FpopulationTotal%3E%20%3Fpopulation%20.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fcountry%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2Fcapital%3E%20%3Fcapital%20.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fcountry%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2Fcurrency%3E%20%3Fcurrency%20.%7D%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=3000000&run=%20Run%20Query%20)

Comment: the more compact formm using SPARQL 1.1 `VALUES`: `SELECT DISTINCT ?country ?population ?capital ?currency WHERE {
values ?type {<http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/WikicatMemberStatesOfTheUnitedNations> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Country>}
?country rdf:type ?type .
?country  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/populationTotal> ?population .
  ?country  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/capital> ?capital .
  ?country  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/currency> ?currency .
}`

Comment: with syntactic sugar even less verbose: `prefix dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT DISTINCT ?country ?population ?capital ?currency WHERE {
values ?type {<http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/WikicatMemberStatesOfTheUnitedNations> dbo:Country}
?country rdf:type ?type ;
dbo:populationTotal ?population ;
dbo:capital ?capital ;
dbo:currency ?currency 
}`

Comment: they still will return the same values

Comment: Did I say something different? I just showed how to use a more compact form. Nevermind, feel free to copy and paste the same UNION pattern for cases when you have more than 2 alternatives.

Comment: I did not say that your solution is wrong or it does not return what I want, there is a problem of readability involved. your compact form is less readable and easy to understand as compared to the one with UNION. Nevermind.